# throwing null pointer exception for saveAllRequirements

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

```
private IRequirementDao requirementDao;

@Override   
public void saveAllRequirements(List<Requirement> requirementsList) {
requirementDao.saveAllRequirements(requirementsList);
}
```

this call to the saveAllRequirements method throwing null pointer exception 
 where IRequirementDao is a interface with some methods shown bellow

```
    public interface IRequirementDao {

        public void saveRequirement(Requirement requirement);
        public List<Requirement> getAllRequirementsCreatedBy(String createdBy);
        public List<Requirement> getAllRequirementsCreatedAfter(Date createdTs);
        public List<Requirement> getAllRequirementsForProject(long projectKey);
        public List<Requirement> getAllRequirementsAsofDt(Date asOfDt);
        public void saveAllRequirements(List<Requirement> requirementsList);
        public List<Requirement> getRequirementsWithTracebilityId(String tracebilityId);
    }
```

Please anyone can help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you implement IRequirementDao ? By looking at this I can say NO.

Comment: this requirementDao reference might be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared an object of type `IRequirementDao`, but according to your code it is neither initialised nor injected.

If you're using some kind of dependency injection, such as Spring or Java EE, you can annotate this field with `@Resource` in order to have it injected - provided that there is at least one implementation of this class available.

If you're not using dependency injection, you'll need to provide an object yourself by assigning an `IRequirementDao` implementation to your field, like so:

```
this.requirementDao = new RequirementDaoImpl(); // or whatever the name of your DAO implementation.
```

Comment: but when i do this i am getting exception like,      java.lang.NullPointerException
com.vxl.appanalytix.dao.impl.RequirementDaoImpl.getSession(RequirementDaoImpl.java:119)

Comment: That might be material for another question... although I'd like suggest double-checking whether all objects inside `RequirementDaoImpl` are instantiated / injected correctly.

Comment: ya thank you so much injection was incorrect in RequirementDaoImpl

Comment: @shravani Accept the answers then, please ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is an interface. You need to implement that interface in a class and then call the `saveAllRequirements` method from your class.

To implement an interface use this format:

```
public class ClassA implements IRequirementDao{
}
```

It will then force you to write your implementation of each method in the interface. Then in your other class you need to initialise your class which implemented the interface:

```
public class ClassB {

    public ClassB{
         ClassA a = new ClassA();
    }

    public void saveAllRequirements(List<Requirement> requirementsList) {
        requirementDao.saveAllRequirements(requirementsList);
    }
}
```